# How do I get PHP to print the unescaped contents of a variable?

Tags: php, escaping

If I have a PHP variable containing a newline, how do I print or echo the contents of that variable so that the newline shows as a backslash followed by an n?

To elaborate, let's say I have the following:

```
$test = "one\ntwo"
```

When I do `echo $test`, I get `one two`.

What I want is literally `one\ntwo`.

I should also clarify that I don't actually specify the variable myself (if I did I could just use single quotes). It's a $_POST variable that I'm dealing with.

Comment: You mean `\n` (or `\r\n`)? What is your goal with this? (Note: I did not give a negative "issue" votes and "answers", was another person)

Comment: Please see elaboration.

Comment: But could you tell me what the real purpose of this (what you are trying to achieve), why not make much sense yet. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, the user is typing in input that might contain more than one line. That input gets passed to a bash script via system(), and then gets passed again to a perl script. The perl script needs to see the newlines as newlines (i.e. as a literal \n).

Comment: Can I be honest, does not seem a safe application, there may be safer ways to do this process. When I say "safe", is not only data security and server, but the code will run without failure. Can you understand me? Maybe you should reformat your question to give focus to the goal, which is to send "strings" to "commands". Understand?

Comment: For now this is okay, but as you say there might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: I recommend editing your question (or create a new one, what you think is best), it will be necessary to understand the process and the goal. I hope I have helped clarify. I wish you success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
$test = 'one\ntwo';
echo $test;
```

Or if it's coming from somewhere else (`$_POST` you say).  Notice double quotes in the search and single in the replace:

```
$test = "one\ntwo";
$test = str_replace("\n", '\n', $test);
echo $test;
```

---

```
one\ntwo
```

Comment: I should've mentioned earlier that I don't actually specify the variable myself; it's a $_POST variable I'm dealing with.

Comment: Edited.  Not sure what you're after here.  Some explanation in the question would help, and there is probably something else that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks. For now this works, but maybe I'll find a better way of doing it later.